# State Management (Session)

Tags: session-state, session-variables

I have one listBox named lstKosnicka and one ADD button named btnDodadi.

```
protected void btnDodadi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DodadiVoKosnicka kosnicka = new DodadiVoKosnicka();
    ListItem stavka = new ListItem();
    List<ListItem> lista = new List<ListItem>();
    stavka = kosnicka.novaStavka(lstPredlog.SelectedItem.Text);

    lstKosnicka.DataSource = Session["kosnicka"] as List<ListItem>;
    lstKosnicka.Items.Add(stavka);
    lstKosnicka.DataBind();
    Session["kosnicka"] = lstKosnicka;
    lstPredlog.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
```

There is one more webForm with other listbox named lstKosnickaNajava, and I want to fill this list wtih the same items as lstKosnicka using Session["kosnicka"], but something is wrong. here is Najava.aspx code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    HttpCookie kolace = Request.Cookies["korisnik"];
    if (kolace != null)
    {
        lblNajavenKorisnik.Text = "Најавен коринсик " + kolace["KorisnickoIme"];
    }
    else
    {
        lblNajavenKorisnik.Text = "Нема најавени корисници";
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        lstKosnickaNajava.DataSource = Session["kosnicka"] as List<ListItem>;

        lstKosnickaNajava.DataBind();

    }
}
```

but when I go from the first page to Najava.aspx the lstKosnickaNajava is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try in btnDodadi_Click()
this code

```
     List<string> lista;
       if (Session["kosnicka"] == null)
        {
            lista = new List<string>();

        }
        else
        {
            lista=(List<string>)Session["kosnicka"];

        }
```

if you add only text the list item can be string.
I forget to ask maybe you do this in PAge_Load method??